# What is post_name field in wp_posts in wordpress for?

Tags: wordpress

I'm migrating an app to wordpress.
We have thousands of wordpress posts that we will insert as custom_types in wordpress database.
What is post_name field in wp_posts for?
Can we have two records with the same post_name?
Is it for friendly urls?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `post_name` is the post's slug. **These must be unique**.

Read more about `WP_Post` member variables [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post#Member_Variables_of_WP_Post).

Comment: I know it's a post slug. What I don't guess and can't find in the doc is why we need a post name. What's the specific reason it must be unique?

Comment: `post_name` is used for generating URIs. Obviously, we don't want duplicate URIs...otherwise, it would cause conflicts (how would WordPress know which post was being referred to?)

Comment: WordPress has the dendency to use very crappy naming conventions. `name` is wrong in `post_name` and in `category_name`, reading those names leads one to believe they are talking about names, while back at the ranch, it actually means *slug*. Why they never used proper naming convention like `post_slug` and `category_slug` is above me

Comment: @PieterGoosen Why? I'd guess for backwards compatibility. Not that it's a good reason, of course...

Answer (score 6):

It is correct that the post_name field stores the slug. However, the post_name field does not have a UNIQUE constraint in the MySQL schema, so while it *should* be unique, it is unfortunately not the case that it *must* be unique. Developers of plugins or tools that write to this table should mind this distinction as the wp_posts table can be corrupted by inserting non-unique values into the post_name table.

I encountered the above issue while resolving a duplication caused by Advanced Custom Fields keying its field and field group definitions off of the contents of this field.